# extract / explode string into variables

Tags: php, extract, explode

i have an the following string from my database:

```
";5;78;27;56;66;71;"
```

how can I extract / explode into variables

```
$a = "5";
$b = "78";
$c = "27";
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: By using [explode()](http://pl1.php.net/explode). Go figure.

Comment: did you tried using `list($a, $b, $c, $e,..) = explode(";", ";5;78;27;56;66;71;");`

Comment: it may help if you gave the problem abit more context, as it doesn't seem like the solution you're asking for is a very efficient one (it may be, I just don't see why you would want to do that with the information you've given us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://www.php.net/explode

```
$data = ";5;78;27;56;66;71;";
$dataArr = explode(';',$data);
for($i = 0; $i < count($dataArr); $i++){
 ${'var'.$i} = $dataArr[$i];
}
```

Explode should return an array of values. Then you iterate through said values and dynamically assign a name to each one.

In my example code, you'll get $var1, $var2, $var3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter( explode(';', ";5;78;27;56;66;71;") );`

The filter is to get rid of some empty values.

Gives you an array of the values:

`Array ( [1] => 5 [2] => 78 [3] => 27 [4] => 56 [5] => 66 [6] => 71 )`